# Multithread Write into Text File in WCF request?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, file-io, .net-4.5

1. I have WCF method which should create file with some data.
2. This file sometimes will be removed by other system.
3. I should append existing file if it exists.
4. Other WCF requests should not lost data.

I thought about different options but looks like that I should implement queue in WCF.

My ideas and attempts:

1. Was used TextWriter.Synchronized. I found that Synchronized is working only for instance for which it was created.
2. Each request will create own file. The request which created file with max index should append all files into one. (not working while when some request will thing that file is already last new requests will be created)
3. Some queue in WCF (how it's possible to implement?)

Test application (emulation of WCF method WritePartToFile):

```
class Program
{
    private static string FileFormat = "file{0}.1001";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int countOfLines = 100;
        var processesCount = 200;

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.1001");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        var expectedFilesCount = processesCount * countOfLines;
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to write. Processes:" + processesCount.ToString() + ". Lines:" + countOfLines + ". Expected lines:" + processesCount * countOfLines);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 1; i < processesCount; i++)
        {
            var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                WritePartToFile("Task:" + i.ToString(), countOfLines);
            });

            tasks.Add(result);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Wait...");
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        var fileName = string.Format(FileFormat, "");
        var lines = 0;
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            lines = File.ReadLines(fileName).Count();
        }

        if (lines != expectedFilesCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!!! Total lines  (" + lines + ") != expected (" + expectedFilesCount + ")");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done. Lines added:" + lines + " Any key to exit.");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void WritePartToFile(string taskName, int countOfLines)
    {
        // Find free file name.
        var fileName = string.Format(FileFormat, "temp_1");

        int fileIndex = 1;
        while (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            fileIndex++;
            fileName = string.Format(FileFormat, "temp_" + fileIndex);
        }

        var logFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
        using (var myWriter = new StreamWriter(logFileStream))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < countOfLines; i++)
            {
                myWriter.WriteLine(taskName + ". Line number: " + i.ToString() + ". Guid:" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }
        }

        // Check is current file has MAX index (next index doesnot exists). Merge items (doesnot working)
        var nextFile = string.Format(FileFormat, "temp_" + fileIndex + 1);
        if (!File.Exists(nextFile))
        {
            var destinationFileName = string.Format(FileFormat, "");

            var mergedLines = new List<string>();
            // Merge all files into destination.
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.1001");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (File.Exists(file))
                {
                    mergedLines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(file));
                }
            }

            logFileStream = new FileStream(destinationFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            using (var myWriter = new StreamWriter(logFileStream))
            {
                foreach (var item in mergedLines)
                {
                    myWriter.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

P.S. I cannot set this WCF method as synchronized because some requests will write data to other files so for them sync is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating multiple FileStreams, one for each task, which doesn't seem correct. Even if they are synchronized, they won't be synchronized between them as they have no way of knowing about the other ones.

What you need to do is create the file handler in your main then pass it to your tasks. Then each task will try to write to the same FileStream. Since you have the requirement that this file can be accessed by other parts of the system, then you cannot keep it open all the time.

Create a new class containing the file handling. This class will handle synchronization with the appropriate locking. Then create an instance of it and pass it to your Tasks, so all Task will have a single, shared access to the file. Inside that class you can add the logic to check if it exists, open the file and close it right away

Comment: Presented code is only example. Really I have WCF calls. I dont know who is calling first and second, I will just recieve many calls in same time.

Comment: The key point here is that you should pass more data to each Task so that they can operate independently and synchronize between them.

Comment: it's not possible while in WCF method I don't have any tasks. Method WritePartToFile is just emulation of service call.